# Getting from Pudong Airport to Pudong Avenue area at night

Tags: public-transport, china, event-based-effects, night-transport, shanghai

This is kind of an inverse of [What is the best way to go to Pudong Airport from downtown Shanghai at night?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/38155/what-is-the-best-way-to-go-to-pudong-airport-from-downtown-shanghai-at-night). My flight lands late enough that metro is closed (and on December 31st!), and I need to get to a hotel near Pudong Avenue metro station.

According to https://www.travelchinaguide.com/cityguides/shanghai/transportation/pudong-airport-bus.htm and http://www.shanghai-airport-transfer.com/transportation/pudong-airport-shuttle-bus.htm, there is a night bus line which stops at "Dongfang Hospital (Pudong Ave)" but I've failed to find exactly where (and so whether it would be close enough to walk to the hotel). There are also hotel shuttle buses going to the area but I might not get to them in time.

Failing that, I assume the only option is taxi. How much is it likely to cost (taking the date into account)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you can, try to get a taxi. Taxi fares are regulated in Shanghai, so insist on using the meter, and you should get something [around 170RMB](https://www.taxifarefinder.com/main.php?city=Shanghai-China&from=Pudong%20International%20Airport%2C%20Pudong%2C%20Shanghai%2C%20China&to=Pudong%20Avenue%2C%20Pudong%2C%20Shanghai%2C%20China&fromCoord=31.1509581,121.80560450000007&toCoord=31.240013,121.51937900000007) at night.
The thing is that New Years Eve is one of the few days (or rather nights) in Shanghai when taxis are scarce and your chances of hailing one on the street are near nil (I had a 1-2 hours walk home last time I was there). That could be (slightly) better at the airport, up to you to find out. Be aware of touts and get a taxi from the official queue and defs not some guy talking you up while you are still in the terminal.

If you go for the night bus, on the website you link to it says it stops at Century Avenue subway station, which would only be a 20 Minute walk to Pudong Avenue station. I have no information whether it does not run on that night, but I would expect it to have regular service.

Worst case, camp it out a few hours at the airport until regular metro/maglev service resumes. I would also get some cash before leaving the airport.

Comment: Thanks! We do have Priority Pass if we end up needing to wait at the airport. The annoying thing would be having paid for the hotel and losing time getting there and checking in in the morning instead of going to see Shanghai.

Comment: Or could you ask your hotel to arrange pick-up for you from the airport? It might cost more but seems the safest bet for me? Note that I don't expect any lounges to be open during those hours. @AlexeyRomanov

Answer (score 4):

Another option is to use [Didi Chuxing](http://www.didichuxing.com/en/) (an Uber clone in China). It shows the amount of money before calling so you do not need to worry about the hefty charge (just checked it now and found it costs 161 RMB).

The one downside is that it is available only in Chinese, but many people at the Pudong Airport speak English and would help you. It is unlikely that the driver speaks English, though it is true of a normal taxi as well. You can pay by credit card (even Amex).